# Custom DataGridView Cell Painting

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to draw my own grid lines because I want thicker lines than the default data grid view lines. This is the code I'm using to do it:

```
 private void dgv_Wafer_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 12))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, e.CellBounds.Bottom), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom));
        }
        using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 6))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, 0), new Point(e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom));
        }
    }
```

The lines are drawn but the horizontal lines won't be drawn in the last column and the vertical lines won't be drawn in the last row. The lines are creating a grid that is a column and row too small. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `e.Handled = true;` to control the painting.  Add back in the default painting of the cells:

```
e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 12)) {
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom),
                         new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom));
}
using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 6)) {
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Top),
                         new Point(e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom));
}
e.Handled = true;
```

Your code was also using 0 for left and top, but the CellBounds values are based on the control's interior space, so you should use `e.CellBounds.Left` and `e.CellBounds.Top`

You might want to adjust the points of your line to account for the thickness of those borders, they are bleeding outside of the cell at the moment.