# Add a MetroButton to DatagridView Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using Metro Framework in Windows forms application. I want to add a column that contains MetroButton(Inherited from Button class). I have came across many articles that told me to inherit from **DataGridViewColumn**  and **DataGridViewTextBoxCell** and overriding the paint method but i am not able to make this. Please suggest the appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23275856/custom-datagridview-cell-painting

Comment: Why not use `DataGridViewButtonCell`? If you are struggling with DataGridView, check this article: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13058/Data-Binding-with-Windows-Forms-Programming-Sm)

Comment: **MetroButton** is a type defined in MetroFramework. DataGridViewButtonCell initialises the cell with **Button** not **MetroButton**. As it is a custom control how can i make use of **MetroButton** in DataGridView.