# Hide specified cell borders in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to hide one or two grid cells from my datagriview. But with this code all the grids are hidden and this is not what I want.

I want to hide one or two rectangles cells from my Datagridview.

## I do not want to hide columns  or data which Contain my cells .

I just wanna hide a Specified cells.

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
```

Comment: Yes, you can modify the cell borders. A bit more convoluted than one would wish for, though.

Comment: Related: [Custom DataGridView Cell Painting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23275856/4934172).

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Not yet,Mr Taw I have trouble calling your function under a button

Comment: how can i call private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e) function    Under  a button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended way to hide or modify cell border style is to code the `CellPainting` event.

Don't worry, no actual painting is required. All you need to do is set a few fields in the `e.AdvancedBorderStyle` parameter.

Here is an example:

[image]

Note the 'vertically merged' look of of the cells in the 3rd column; same for the 'horizontally merged' cells at the bottom. Also the double border of a cell in the 5th column.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender,
                                        DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex == 6)
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex == 1)
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex == 4)
    {
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.All = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.InsetDouble;
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
    }
}
```

Note that hiding borders is rather straight forward : Simply hide the right or the bottom border;  other borderstyles require some trial and error (or a deeper understanding ;-)

Here I first set the style for all sides but as it paints the botton white (at least that's what I think it does) I then set the botton border back to single.

You may want to streamline the way the checks are done; this is just a simple example.

**Update**:

Here is a code to make the merging more dynamic: Use the `mergeCells` function to mark a cell for merging or un-merging with its right or bottom neighbour:

```
private void mergeCells(DataGridViewCell cell, bool mergeH, bool mergeV)
{
    string m = "";
    if (mergeH) m += "R";  // merge horizontally by hiding the right border line
    if (mergeV) m += "B"; // merge vertically by hiding the bottom border line
    cell.Tag =  m == "" ? null : m;
}
```

The `CellPainting` now looks like this:

```
private void customDGV1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    DataGridViewCell cell = ((DataGridView)sender)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
    if (cell.Tag == null) return;
    string hide = cell.Tag.ToString();

    if (hide.Contains("R")) 
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    else
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;

    if (hide.Contains("B")) 
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
    else 
        e.AdvancedBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;

}
```

**Update 2:**

If you want to apply this to the `ColumnHeaders` you need to turn off `dgv.EnableHeadersViualStyles` first..

Comment: I call this method under a button but it signals a mistake.
How can I call it properly under a button

Comment: It needs to work from the CellPainting event. What you can do in a button click event is set some data at class level, maybe, or in the cell.Tag, which you then can use in the checks in above code. I can give you an example but you need to be clearer what 'hiding' a cell means. Hiding a single is not possible at all. Hiding borders is, as you can see. But if you hide all four borders of a cell the result is a 'cross' of 5 cells. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to hide The line of two cells from two colones to form a cell like what your image shows at the fourth column

Comment: I have updated the answer with a dynamic way for merging horizontally and or vertically..

Comment: Thanks for the reply now I want to know how to use this event under a button        can u give   an example  about use it Under buutton

Comment: Well call it like any other function! You need to know which cell you target and add false and true as paremeters for the merging you wanted : `mergeCells(dataGridView1[2,1], false, true);`

Comment: help about call function dataGridView1_CellPainting

Comment: You don't call it, it is an event and gets called by the system for each cell that needs to ne painted. You can trigger is with dgv.Invalidate().

Comment: The cell if you wanted to use it but I suggest using `dgv.Invalidate();`. No params!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation>>>> I KNOW HOW TO MARK AS ANSWER

Comment: Good. Sorry if that came across the wrong way but so many newbies don't.. :-)