# Delete column's lines from specific row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using a data-grid-view Is there any way which I can delete lines from columns but only in a specific row?

I found this:

```
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
```

but it deletes lines from all columns.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484960/how-can-i-hide-a-specified-cells-that-i-want-in-datagridview/52487741#52487741) !

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can i handle this with datagridview values? I mean if row[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString()=="1"

Comment: The code in the link already contains conditions. Simply replace or append your conditions! Try it and report back!