# C# custom control in WinForm with DataGridView and bar graph

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm currently working on a Windows program using c#, and customer give these figures below

[Figure 1: data list record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myWz0.png)

Tap the subject like "Player", "Class" or "Name of Student" to update the record display in ascending or descending order.

Student name looks like TextBox has border, and editable.

Individual Record "more info" is clickable like hyperlink.

I'm considering use DataGridView, but how to achieve these style? (how to make cell like TextBox? The hyperlink in the cell? Another ways to do that?)

About the graph, is there any free libraries or ways to make bar graph like below?

[Figure 2: bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMUT0.png)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Edited**

Here is what I tried so far:
[Figure 3: demo-test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9EO7.jpg)

And my questions:

1. How to custom header like figure 1?
2. I have no idea how to use DataGridCellStyles to make cell has border, any sample codes?

I already try to describe my questions as possible and show what I have done, but got 3 downvotes?????

Comment: Perfect... We know what you want... can you also share what code you have written and what issue you are facing in that?

Comment: For the borders: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484960/hide-specified-cell-borders-in-datagridview/52487741#52487741) - for the Header: Set a suitable ColumnHeadersDefaultCell For the chart USe the MSChart control.Style font. For the Year picker: Use a separate set of, maybe, Labels.

Comment: @TaW thanks for the hints

Comment: I pasted the chart hint into the cellstyle text; don't let that confuse you. You can get a 'link-like' functionality by coding the cellmouseclick event. Basic ordering is built-in; custom sort is also possible with a little code; do consider data-binding for the dgv with a a bindingsource and also for the chart.series.points!

Answer (score -1):

You can define DataGridCellStyles to make them appear the way you want. However, a lot of such trivial things are already taken care if you use Control Libraries like: DevExpress Grid or Infragistics (I'd prefer DevExpress).

For the Graph - you again can use a Charting Library like: Dundas Chart, ZedGraph etc

Comment: Are any of these free?

Comment: Good stuff isnt free :)