# Set a DataGridView Cell Border Style to selected column only

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I would like to do this border style on my 3rd column's cells.
Can anyone help me to accomplish this in DataGridView.

*I'm talking about the selected part with red rectangle:*

[image: Red rectangle]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484960/hide-specified-cell-borders-in-datagridview/52487741?r=SearchResults&s=1|81.8816#52487741) can help..

Answer (score 2):

The borders which we can see in the specified column in the question are not cell borders. Cell borders are those dot lines between rows. So setting `AdvancedBorderStyle` in `CellPaint` method will not be much of help.

You need to perform some settings and do a bit custom painting.

These are some settings which helps you to achieve such style for rows and cells:

- Setting Padding for the column
- Setting row height
- Setting cell border styles to none
- Removing row headers
- Handling `CellPaint` event:

  - Painting cell but contents.
  - Painting dotted border at top and bottom of rows.
  - Painting cell contents normally or like a text box for specific column.

**Example**

```
var specificColumn = 1;

dataGridView1.Columns[specificColumn].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(10);
dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 45;
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;

dataGridView1.CellPainting += (obj, args) =>
{
    if (args.ColumnIndex < 0 || args.RowIndex < 0)
        return;
    args.Paint(args.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All & 
        ~DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
    var r = args.CellBounds;
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black))
    {
        pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot;
        args.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Top);
        args.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Right, r.Bottom);
    }
    r.Inflate(-8, -8);
    if (args.ColumnIndex == specificColumn)
        TextBoxRenderer.DrawTextBox(args.Graphics, r, $"{args.FormattedValue}",
            args.CellStyle.Font, System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.TextBoxState.Normal);
    else
        args.Paint(args.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
    args.Handled = true;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Right. I probably mis-read the question, focusing on *I'm talking about the selected part with red rectangle* (and the drawing). I interpreted it as a border applied to a specific Column bounds.

Comment: @Jimi The title is talking about applying border style to specific column. In that case, `AdvancedBorderStyle` is quite useful. But the image is saying a different thing (what I interpreted in the answer).

Comment: I think you got it right. The Cells' style shown in the image is probably not what the OP already has but what he wants to achieve.