# How to merge empty 4 cells and 1 cell with a value in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview in my WinForm application. This datagridview is getting filled with measurement results dinamically. On the third column program shows a value that is calculated only once for every 5 rows. So i want to merge empty cells of these 5 rows and show calculated value in one cell as a element of 5 rows. Please see screenshot.
[image: datagridview]

I have checked the posts about merging cells on here and other several sites, but they are based on merging cells with same value. This is not my case.

[How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms)

This is how i add values to datagridview;

```
if (cnt == 0 || cnt == 5)
{
taper = calcTap(tap1, tap2);
int index = daGridMeas.Rows.Add();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = a[0].ToString();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = a[1].ToString();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = taper.ToString("0.0000");

taper.ToString("0.0000"));

cnt = 1;
}

else
{                 
int index = daGridMeas.Rows.Add();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = a[0].ToString();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = a[1].ToString();
daGridMeas.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value = "";

cnt++;
}
if (cnt == 1)
{
tap1 = float.Parse(a[1]);
}
```

How can i merge this cells together and fill it with calculated taper value?

Comment: You can't. All you can do is remove some cell borders. Or overlay stuff. But any sort of actual merging is not supported.

Comment: How can remove these specific cells' borders?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484960/hide-specified-cell-borders-in-datagridview/52487741?r=SearchResults&s=1|105.5640#52487741) !